Confused about を足元に / how is this sentence divided?

店内はいつもの喧噪を足元に、まるで反転したかのように静まっている

The character is sitting in a bar. The place is quiet as there are no clients atm and they are discussing a girl's death.
The narrator thinks this.
What I'm stumbled is, what to make of を足元に here?
I understand the sentence is akin to "The usual rucks it was like it was reversed and the k place was quiet"
But I'm not sure what to make of を足元に here? I'm aware of を に grammar but I don't see how it fits? The characters are sitting together for further context

This appears to be the AをBに construction, where A is いつもの喧噪 and B is 足元.

Meaning and transitivity of ゴミ袋を手に立ち上がる
Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした

So the literal translation is this:

店内はいつもの喧噪を足元に、まるで反転したかのように静まっている。
The store interior, with its usual bustle now at its feet, is quiet as if it were inverted.

But "having the noise at the feet" is indeed a puzzling expression without context. Maybe something noisy is taking place downstairs?

No, the place is basically desert and there are only two people. I can only guess he-s talking about his emotional turmoil, or the convo he's having with his friend.
